# How to view complete print output in a terminal?

Tags: terminal

I'm currently working with a software called [CleGo](http://cpc.cs.qub.ac.uk/summaries/AEIQ_v1_0.html) , which is written in O'Caml and I use it in the Toplevel mode. This program computes all Clebsch-Gordan coefficients for a given group representation. Unfortuantely, I can't get the complete output in the terminal. I get:

```
[[[("-1", ("(0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,)1", "(0,0,0,0,0,0,-1,0,)1"));
("1", ("(0,0,0,0,0,1,-1,0,)1", "(0,0,0,0,0,-1,1,0,)1"));
("-1", ("(0,0,0,0,1,-1,0,0,)1", "(0,0,0,0,-1,1,0,0,)1"));
...]]]
```

and I need the complete output that is indicated by "..." in the output. Is there some terminal restrictions that restricts the output to a certain length or is this a special problem of the software?

Any ideas or suggestions would be awesome!

Comment: From the appearance, it is a limitation in the software.  It might be configurable (the example is 182 characters, which seems odd - perhaps against a limit of 200 characters).

Comment: @ThomasDickey Yes thanks, it was indeed a software limitation which could be changed by #print_length n;; in the Toplevel mode